# How to change the font color of actionBar Tab to distinguish between selected and unselected?

Tags: android, colors

In android actionBar Tabs, when you select a tab, that particular tab gets the blue-Underline-Highlight, and the remaining doesn't. Which is fine.

But my project wants the particular TEXT-COLOR of SELECTED tab to be of say BLUE color and all the other UNSELECTED tab's TEXT-COLOR to be of say GREY color.

How could I acheive variation in Text-Color ?

As far as I could go I made the text-color as BLUE.. but its blue color text for SELECTED and UNSELECTED TABS also.

Following is the code am using at the moment ( created in theme.xml in res/value/ )

```
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00A7F4</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/custom_actionbar_tab_text_style</item> 

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00A7F4</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/custom_actionbar_tab_text_style</item> 
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabs"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00A7F4</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00A7F4</item>
</style>

<style name="custom_actionbar_tab_text_style">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use color state list
Create `res/color/filename.xml`
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

and then use it 
`<item name="android:textColor">@color/filename</item>`

Learn more : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: The above is correct, but you will need to set android:state_selected too, to set the font colour of the selected tab. E.g.
`<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#000000" />`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
```

or in code

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/filename</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i combine all lines together than answer would be following code. Create new folder under res folder( res/color/filename.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- selected -->
<item android:color="#B3FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
```